# Trouble Deploying r shiny app with dygraphs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I'm currently attempting to deploy my R shiny app which uses the dygraphs package to shinyapps.io. My app works fine locally but when I try to deploy it says the webpage cannot be found - "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error". My UI code is:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("MyApp"),

  fluidRow(
      column(12,
          p("Info Text")
          ,dygraphOutput("plot")
            ) 
          )
))
```

and server code is:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  library(shiny)
  library(dygraphs)



    output$plot<- renderDygraph({
        data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep =",",na.strings="-")
        dygraph(data, main = "Plot") %>%
          dyLegend(width = 170 , 
                   labelsSeparateLines = TRUE , 
                   show = "always") %>%
          dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE)
```

When I remove the dygraphOutput function from the UI code the app deploys successfully. Has anyone experienced similar problems with dygraphs?

Comment: i think there might be a problem with your `csv`, can you do `dput(data)` and post the output here

Comment: structure(list(Year = 2009:2015, A = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.02, 0.03), B = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01), C = c(0.06, 0.06, 0.08, 0.09, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14)), .Names = c("Year", 
"A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine for me, i think the issue is with your `csv` file. You can see that my app works fine with this code:

#### Server

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  data <- readRDS("data.rds")

  output$plot<- renderDygraph({
    req(data)
    dygraph(data, main = "Plot") %>% dyLegend(width = 170 , labelsSeparateLines = TRUE , show = "always") %>%dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE)
  })

})
```

#### ui

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MyApp"),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,p("Info Text"),dygraphOutput("plot")) 
  )
)
```

#### Folder structure

[image]

#### Final Output

[image]

#### The app hosted on aws

http://52.39.186.219:3838/Dygraphs/

Comment: This works fine for me when I run it locally also, but once I deploy it that's when I encounter the issue. Are you able to deploy the app with no issues?

Comment: you better save your data as `.rds` file and load that file into Rshiny in a global space https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/readRDS

Comment: As you suggested I saved as .rds file and loaded in the file using the readRDS function but I'm still experiencing the same issue

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for checking that out. Could the issue be something to do with the subscription on my account?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you're deploying to `shinyapps.io` make sure you dont set any drictories, other than that I don't know unfortunately